# Adding a link to an entire flexbox

Tags: css

I can't figure out how to make an entire flexbox a link without the content messing up somehow. It gets complicated for me because I have an image at the top of each box.

My flexboxes are set up as:

```
.cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.card {
    flex: 0 1 100%;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #888;
}

.card-content {
    padding: 10px;
}

.card-content p {
    line-height: 120%;
}

.card-header {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-position: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

And some media queries:

```
@media all and (min-width: 50em) {
    .card {flex: 0 1 30%;}
    .card-content p {font-size: .9em;}
    .card-content a {font-size: .9em;}
}
```

And the HTML structure of each box/card:

```
<div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" style="background-image: url(https://)"></div>
        <div class="card-content">
            <h3>Header</h3>
            <p>Description.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Again, no matter where I put an A tag, it'll majorly mess up the formatting.

Comment: Can you post something (image, jsfiddle, etc.) to let us understand better the problem?

Comment: Just add the a tag at the same level of 'card' elements and use absolute position to put it over the entire flexbox.

Answer (score 5):

> How to make an entire flexbox a link

Don't use a `div` with a class of `.card` as a wrapper use a link instead with the same class, everything else is the same.

The whole card is now a link!

```
  <a href="#" class="card">
        <div class="card-header" style="background-image: url(https://)"></div>
        <div class="card-content">
            <h3>Header</h3>
            <p>Description.</p>
        </div>
    </a>
```

Comment: Wow. I feel like a dummy! Thanks!

Comment: isn't block level tag inside an inline tag semantically incorrect?

Comment: Not for links. No.